# How does JVM deal with dynamic classes

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

Class definitions are stored in the Method Area, as the Java Virtual Machine Specification says ([The Java® Virtual Machine Specification Java SE 7 Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4)):

> The method area is created on virtual machine start-up. Although the
>   method area is logically part of the heap, simple implementations may
>   choose ***not to either garbage collect or compact*** it.

As we know, some bytecode tools like **ASM**, **cglib**, **javassist**, Hibernate and Spring frameworks are using them. For a common class file, JVM loads and parses and initializes and finally uses it, I am confused about how does JVM deal with the classes generated by bytecode tools dynamically. My questions are:

1. If JVM loads, parses and initializes the dynamic classes as the common class file?
2. Are they stored in the Method Area as well?
3. How does JVM unload and clean the dynamic class definitions to prevent itself from occurring an OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: how could the JVM know to treat dynamic classes any differently than 'normal' classes?

Comment: @down voter, could you give me an answer about Q3?

Comment: @NathanHughes Lambdas are one example where these classes are treated differently (see my answer)

Comment: btw i didn't downvote this, i upvoted. i appreciate the part about lambdas especially.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All class are loaded at runtime, possibly compiled to native code.  As such there is nothing special about class generated after the program has started.

> If JVM loads, parses and initializes the dynamic classes as the common class file?

It loads the same way as class which existed when the program started.

> Are they stored in the Method Area as well?

They are stored the same way in fact it is hard to tell if a class is dynamic or not.

> How does JVM unload and clean the dynamic class definitions to prevent itself from occurring an OutOfMemoryError?

The JVM can unload classes when the ClassLoader they are in is unloaded.  This is true whether the classes are dynamic or not.

> how could the JVM know to treat dynamic classes any differently than 'normal' classes?

There is one example of dynamic classes which are special.  These are the lambda classes which are generated at runtime.  What makes them different is they are not bound to a class loader, they don't even have a normal class name.  They get unloaded when all the instances of that class are unused.

From `InnerClassLambdaMetafactory`

```
UNSAFE.defineAnonymousClass(targetClass, classBytes, null);
```

The class has no class name attached to it (nor a ClassLoader)

Comment: "In Java 8, the meta space doesn't produce an OutOfMemoryError" it doesn't? What's `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metadata space` then?

Comment: @eis True, the maximum size of the meta space is much higher but you can still get an OOME, it is just less likely.

Comment: Actually, even the “anonymous” classes have a name as it’s part of the class file format. You will see it when debugging. What makes them special is that the name doesn’t need to be unique and these classes cannot be accessed via their name (as they are not recorded within a class loader). Btw. this feature is also used by `MethodHandle`s internally (that’s why it also exists in Oracle’s Java 7 implementation).

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between `.class` data on the file system, inside a jar file or dynamically created by tools like ASM.

In fact when the class loader loads the class, it's just a `byte[]` how that byte array is populated with `.class` data is up to the class loader to get it from the filesystem, inside a jar or zip file, from a URL, dynamically generated etc.

**If JVM loads, parses and initializes the dynamic classes as the common class file?**

As I said it is exactly the same.  The JVM doesn't know the difference.

**Are they stored in the Method Area as well?**

Again, JVM doesn't know the difference so I guess.

**How does JVM unload and clean the dynamic class definitions to prevent itself from occurring an OutOfMemoryError**

The same way as non-dynamic classes.  by unloading although I don't know how often this happens

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact, I'm just confused about Q3